# pipe mplayer output to other tool

Tags: pipe, streaming, mplayer

I'm trying to play an online live stream via mplayer and pipe the audio from that stream to another tool.

Playing the stream works fine:

```
mplayer http://user:pass@192.168.0.1:8080/stream.flv
```

But now I'm not sure how I can get the audio stream of that. I managed to write to a wav file via:

```
mplayer -ao pcm:file=/tmp/out.wav -vo null -vc null -novideo http://user:pass@192.168.0.1:8080/stream.flv
```

But how can I do something like this:

```
mplayer [options] http://user:pass@192.168.0.1:8080/stream.flv | sox -r 44100 -b 32 -c 1 -e floating-point -t raw - -r 16000 -b 16 -e signed-integer -c 1 -t raw /tmp/out.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar, redirecting `mplayer` output to `lame`, and I solved it with a FIFO. Try this:

```
mkfifo fifo
mplayer -ao pcm:file=fifo [option] [stream_url] &
sox [option] fifo /tmp/out.wav
rm fifo
```